# How can I use ng-repeat to generate custom html tags or directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create some custom tag using angularjs with ng-repeat but its not working, its giving tag name in double quotation marks.

Good result is: shouldn't show `<div>` or another tags.

I have a demo version here : http://plnkr.co/edit/aT2UjMIGGLvnCGFxXC3a?p=preview
 or you can use code snippet

my code is:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.items = [
   {
     "name":"directive1"
   },
   {
     "name":"directive2"
   },
   {
     "name":"div"
   }
 ];
})

.directive("showitems", function(){
 return {
  restrict: "E",
  template: '<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items"><div class="item-title">{{item.name}}</div><div class="item-body"><{{item.name}}></{{item.name}}></div></div>'
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <showitems></showitems>
</div>
```

Comment: you just want to display the tags like <dir1></dir1> or render them as html???

Comment: @Harsh, yes its exactly that i want, i want to render them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrapping {{item.name}} into its own tag, make a customTag directive. This can take a string (the tag name) and create and compile an element with it.

```
.directive("customTag", function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      //pass customTag in as part of the directive attribute
      var customTag = attrs.customTag;
      if (!customTag) return;
      var customElem = angular.element("<" + customTag + "></" + customTag + ">");

      //replace your custom element directive with the compiled one
      element.replaceWith($compile(customElem)(scope));
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your template.html:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div class="item-title">{{item.name}}</div>
   <div class="item-body">
      <!-- This will use customTag directive to create element item.name -->
      <div data-custom-tag="{{item.name}}"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

A div tag (or any non-directive) wouldn't be too useful because it doesn't get any innerHTML or behavior like directive1 and directive2 would get. This of course is a simple example, you may want to put some more checks or restrictions in there, but this should get you started.

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q7edf808/) that builds on your example.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, doing something like `<{{item.name}}></{{item.name}}>` will never work in angular since the markups aren't treated as new DOM elements. A much better, and more manageable approach is to write directives for all possible `types` you'd want to render as DOM elements.

Also, to know more about DOM manipulations from within a directive, read up about `$compile`: [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

An alternate way of doing this would be something like this in your directive template:

```
<directive1 ng-if="directiveType == 'directive1'"></directive1>
<directive2 ng-if="directiveType == 'directive1'"></directive2>
<directive3 ng-if="directiveType == 'directive1'"></directive3>
```

And in your controller/directive, you must declare `directiveType` to the type of directive you want to render.

Comment: thanks for helping me, i give you upvote, can you give me an example for how can i use `$compile` for do this job.

Comment: Its a little hard for me to do that since I don't know the context of what you're trying to achieve here. I'm going to add some code to my answer of an approach that you might find even simpler, so that you understand.

Comment: thanks a lot for your ways that you show me, i accept patrick that use `$compile` that you said before but he said more details, thanks again :)